# Localhost redirection in ASP.NET.

Tags: asp.net

I have two websites in my solution. I want to redirect to a webpage of 2nd website from the webpage of first using the session of first website how can i do that?

Answer (score 0):

There is no built-in solution, but you can handle this issue by yourself. Have a look at the following post at codeproject.com, the author provides a small library that provides the necessary functionality:

[Sharing Sessions across Applications](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/session/sharedsession.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

I would use SQL Server to store the session state between the two applications.  This is a good starting point:

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/317604